# Using '\displaymath' directives in docstrings formulas

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I am using the Sphinx documentation package to document a small Python tool kit that I am working on and I would like to describe the mathematical formulas that the various modules implement by listing them in LaTeX format in the Python docstrings.

It is pretty easy to achieve this with `:math:` or `.. math::` directives for reStructuredText, for example:

```
.. math::
   \\displaymath \\sum_{i=1}^{\\infty} x_{i}
```

but the `\\displaymath` directive is just highlighted as red text when in a Python docstring. When used in a `.rst` file (e.g. `index.rst`) this works as expected, and the sub- and super-scripts for the summation are directly below and above the summation symbol.

Is this simply not supported for docstrings, or am I doing something wrong or not doing something that I need to be doing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not need `\displaymath` in Sphinx and no additional escaping backslashes for `\sum` and `\infty`.

The following example function renders fine in both html and latex output when called with `.. autofunction::`:

```
def test_func(x):
    """This function will try to calculate:

    .. math::
        \sum_{i=1}^{\\infty} x_{i}

    good luck!
    """
    pass
```

You have to use the `.. math::` directive as inline math (`:math:`) doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, thanks for that!  I do still need to doublebackslash for the fraction '¥frac{a}{b}' syntax.  I wonder if there is a list of what does and doesn't require the backslash?  Also, displaymath isn't required, but it seems that embedded summations won't go to displaymath mode.  I guess I can live with it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Normally you should not need any escaping backslashes, I think. `\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i}}{\infty}` works perfectly for me. I am using sphinx 1.1.3, docutils 0.8.1 and `sphinx.ext.mathjax` for math. What do you use?

Comment: You do need the extra escape backslashes. If you use a Python raw string, as in `r"""...."""`, then you do not need extra escape characters.

Comment: if one is using 'sphinx.ext.mathjax' and needs inline commenting. The following worked for me 
`:math:`(X_{i})` 
`

Comment: Still escaping `infty` twice though... Probably a typo?